# How to check if files exists when project start run?

Tags: java

I am new in java programmming so maybe my question will seem to some of you silly.

I use netbeans for my java web project.
Whenever projecct is fired I need to check if some files exsiting in file system.

So, I would like to know where I can put function to check if file exists(i.e. where is start up project in projcet) 
in operating system when project starts?

Answer (score 0):

#### Java1 or higer

```
File file = new File("c:/foo.txt");
file.isFile();      // true - file is regular file (not a directory or smth. else)
file.exists();      // true - file exists
file.canRead();     // true - file exists and readable
file.canWrite();    // true - file exists and writable
```

#### Java7 or higher

```
Path file = Paths.get("c:/foo.txt");
Files.isRegularFile(file);    // true - file is regular file (not a directory or smth. else)
Files.exists(file);           // true - file exists
Files.isReadable(file);       // true - file exists and readable
Files.isWritable(file);       // true - file exists and writable
```